# SharePoint workflow Current Item is being ignored after a Pause

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I have a questions I hope someone has the answer to.

- it is a 2010 workflow running on a SharePoint 2013 hosted environment.
- The workflow was created by an "Admin account"
- I have edited the workflow using my account which is part of the admin group on SharePoint. I am using SharePoint designer to edit the workflow.
- The workflow doesn't throw any errors and my code should "work" in theory/practice because it is rather simple.

Here's the problem:

- The workflow pauses until it reaches a date
  -When it comes out of the pause, it seems to ignore my case statement.
- All my debugging logs indicate it should go down an IF statement but it doesn't
- One other IF statement works just fine coming out of the PAUSE.

**Else if Current Item:Category equals value PTO**

Category is a drop down field
The debug log says Category = PTO
Every item in the field statement is obtained from a Pick List!
I have moved this statement to the top of the IF list and it will still be ignored.

I don't understand why it is not dropping into this IF statement while another case it works fine.

Could it be a permission issue?

Comment: Can you show us more of the actions and conditions of the workflow (in pseudocode)?

Comment: **if Current Item:Category equals value COMPEN** < ---drops into this just fine if it is set. There really isn't much to this. I broke it down to it's simplest form so I could see it work but it never does. There is one more piece of information I failed to mention. I added "PTO" to the drop down list. So basically all my new options are not working.

Comment: If you want to rule out a permissions issue try to put the code into an impersonation step.

Comment: okay thanks! I will try this.